# Leaflet map: filtering by year

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geojson

I've posted this question here before, but probably left out some context so I'm going to try again!  I have four geojson layers, each in array format.  To access info in these layers, it seems to be nested like so: layers-object-features-properties.

Here is a sample of data structure:

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
"info_city": "Wuerzburg",
"info_date": 2009,
"info_status": "fac"
},
```

The property I want to filter by is date , which, in my data, is field "info_date".  I wrote the following function, picking a random year to filter by as a test.  This will be linked to a range-slider bar on my map, ranged from 1971-2016.

```
function filterByYear(data){
    console.log(data)
    f = data.filter(function(d){ return d.features.properties.info_date === '2016';})
    console.log(f) 
    return f;
    }
```

As an aside, I have also tried this using underscore.js, to no avail:

```
f=_.filter(data, function(d) { return d.properties.info_date == 2016; });
```

So, I call this function where I'm indexing the range slider, like so, using the layer geoJsonLayers.fellows as the input.

```
    if (index == 2015) {
    filterByYear(geoJsonLayers.fellows)
  }
```

Nothing happens, and in the filterByYear function, I am able to console.log (data), but nothing consoles for (f).  What am I doing wrong here?  And, is there an easier way to filter by year, as what I'm really trying to do is filter as the user moves through the range slider, i.e. when index = 1980, only data where "info_date" == 1980 would be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely using "strict equal" for your filter check. In your data structure, `info_date` is an *integer*, but you're strictly checking against the *string* `'2016'`.

Try using `==` instead of `===` and see if that fixes your problem. You could also try checking against `2016` instead of `'2016'`.

---

Edit: If you want to solve your problem of dynamically checking the year, you could pass the year into `filterByYear` as an argument:

```
function filterByYear(data, year) {
  f = data.filter(function(d) { 
    return d.features.properties.info_date == year;
  });
  return f;
}
```

---

Edit 2: The following works for me using (approximately) your sample data.

```
k = [{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "info_city": "Wuerzburg",
    "info_date": 2009,
    "info_status": "fac"
  }
},{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "info_city": "Berlin",
    "info_date": 2016,
    "info_status": "fac"
  }
}];

function filterByYear(data, year) {
  f = data.filter(function(d) { 
    return d.properties.info_date == year;
  });
  return f;
}


filterByYear(k, 2009); // Returns array of one object
filterByYear(k, 2016); // Returns array of one object
filterByYear(k, 2008); // Returns empty array
```

Comment: Thanks Will! Still no luck though.  I tried your suggestion.  I think the data might be nested in a weird way and it can't access the data.  I'm not sure how I would show that though.

Comment: Are you working in the browser? At the beginning of `filterByYear()` you can `console.log(data)` to see the structure of the object and figure out how `info_date` is nested.

Comment: Will - thanks, I've tried doing that and I think I have a better handle on the structure, but I still can't seem to console log anything within the 'filterByYear()' function (within filter by year).  For example, when I try to console.log 'd' or 'f', to see what's going on, nothing shows.  I'm unsure why this is.  Thus, it seems like this is where it might be breaking.

Comment: See my "Edit 2". You should be able to copy that into the console directly and have it work. Then, instead of `k`, use your actual data and edit the part `d.properties.info_date` to match your data's structure. Keep in mind that the `data` argument of `filterByYear` needs to be an array.

Comment: Thank you Will!  So, after doing some more digging, and seeing your response, it appears that maybe my data structure is not as simple as I made it seem.  Basically, I have an array called "geoJsonLayers", which consists of 4 layers.  When I console "geoJsonLayers", I get the 4 layers:                                                                                               Object { residents: Object, faculty: Object, residentsFellows: Object, fellows: Object }

Comment: When I open "fellows" object, it seems to be nested like so: "_layers", then I get 100 some "objects".  These appear to be the individual points on my leaflet map.  When I click on one, I can access "feature", then "properties", then "info_date".  This seems like a more complex nesting structure than a simple array, yet I'm not sure how my filterByYear function should reflect this data structure.  It seems as if I want to filter the layer.  Sorry if I wasn't clear at first, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: The idea, by the way, was to load the layer in the map as "point-to-layer", and then filter that layer instead of filtering the original  geojson multiple times and then having to redraw the layer when each filter was applied.  Hope that makes sense?